# How can you write a VBA script to delete all cells in a range containing a certain string?

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a large range of cells, and I want to delete all cells containing just a "," or similar, how can I express this in code? I was thinking something along the lines of

```
If Range("C1:C100").Value = "," Then 
Active.Cell.Delete Shift:=xlRight
```

I know this is terrible, but hopefully it gets my point across.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try to run the code in your sample? Any error messages? You learn faster by doing it yourself and then asking questions about the problems you run into. :)

Comment: Think about iterating through the cells in a given range...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm going to test telyln's answer a little bit and try figure out myself what's going on. I'll get back if I'm still stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

conceptually (not in front of Excel right now)

```
dim cel as range
for each cel in Range("C1:C100")
   if cel.Value = "," Then
      cel.Delete Shift:=xlRight 
   end if
next cel
```

Comment: Excellent. This worked. I just had to change the Delete line to `Delete Shift:=xlToLeft`

Thanks a million!